# Get all the values from the table that match values in an array?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have an array like this

```
string[] Reportable = { "1", "3", "5" };
```

I have a table Products in my database with a column PartNumber and I can get all partNumbers with e.g value 2 like this.

```
var result = db.Products.ToList().Where(product => product.PartNumber == 2);
```

But I want to get all values from the database that match values in my array Reportable. Eg if my table look like this

```
ID   Name   PartNumber
1    Name1  1
2    Name2  1
3    Name3  2
4    Name4  3
5    Name5  4
6    Name3  5
```

The result from my query should be rows with id 1,2,4,6 because I don't have number 2 and 4 in my array.

Edit

I'am trying to get all PartNumbers that starts with a number in the Reportable array, not only exact match. If I have the number 20 in my array, valid numbers from the query would be e.g 2010, 20221, 20 and 20111 but not e.g 25111, 10333, 11000. I have found the extension method StartsWith() but I do not get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Contains` like this:

```
var result = 
     db.Products.Where(product => 
          Reportable.Any(r => product.PartNumber.StartsWith(r))
      ).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is it possible to modify to start with instead of contains? E.g I want all PartNumbers that start with a number in the  Reportable array. If I have the number 20 in my array, valid numbers from the query would be e.g 2010, 20221 and 20111 but not e.g 25111. I have found the extension method `StartsWith()` but I do not get it to work.

Comment: @Xtreme - it is possible, you just need to use the `Any` method instead of `Contains`. I have updated the answer